# Set keyframe interval in ffmpeg when using nvenc

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, cuda, h.265

OBS uses nvenc when encoding live streams. In the guide "[NVIDIA NVENC OBS Guide](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/guides/broadcasting-guide/)", an advanced option is listed as:

> Keyframe Interval: Set to 2. Streaming platforms may limit what you can select here, and most require a setting of 2.

I want to do the same with ffmpeg, and we know the option exists in the nvenc API. However, listing the encoder's options with `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc` (full output pasted below), the usual `-keyint` or `-g` options are not found. The most relevant ones are `-forced-idr` and `-strict_gop`.

How to set keyframe interval, either as number of frames or time duration in seconds, when using nvenc?

(While we are at it, the "Psycho Visual Tuning", "Max B-Frames" options in the guide are also missing. The latter should in theory be accessible by `-bf:v 4`. What about the former?)

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Encoder h264_nvenc [NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder]:
    General capabilities: delay hardware
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: cuda cuda d3d11va d3d11va
    Supported pixel formats: yuv420p nv12 p010le yuv444p p016le yuv444p16le bgr0 rgb0 cuda d3d11
h264_nvenc AVOptions:
  -preset            <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding preset (from 0 to 11) (default medium)
     default         0            E..V......
     slow            1            E..V...... hq 2 passes
     medium          2            E..V...... hq 1 pass
     fast            3            E..V...... hp 1 pass
     hp              4            E..V......
     hq              5            E..V......
     bd              6            E..V......
     ll              7            E..V...... low latency
     llhq            8            E..V...... low latency hq
     llhp            9            E..V...... low latency hp
     lossless        10           E..V......
     losslesshp      11           E..V......
  -profile           <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding profile (from 0 to 3) (default main)
     baseline        0            E..V......
     main            1            E..V......
     high            2            E..V......
     high444p        3            E..V......
  -level             <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding level restriction (from 0 to 51) (default auto)
     auto            0            E..V......
     1               10           E..V......
     1.0             10           E..V......
     1b              9            E..V......
     1.0b            9            E..V......
     1.1             11           E..V......
     1.2             12           E..V......
     1.3             13           E..V......
     2               20           E..V......
     2.0             20           E..V......
     2.1             21           E..V......
     2.2             22           E..V......
     3               30           E..V......
     3.0             30           E..V......
     3.1             31           E..V......
     3.2             32           E..V......
     4               40           E..V......
     4.0             40           E..V......
     4.1             41           E..V......
     4.2             42           E..V......
     5               50           E..V......
     5.0             50           E..V......
     5.1             51           E..V......
  -rc                <int>        E..V...... Override the preset rate-control (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     constqp         0            E..V...... Constant QP mode
     vbr             1            E..V...... Variable bitrate mode
     cbr             2            E..V...... Constant bitrate mode
     vbr_minqp       8388612      E..V...... Variable bitrate mode with MinQP (deprecated)
     ll_2pass_quality 8388616      E..V...... Multi-pass optimized for image quality (deprecated)
     ll_2pass_size   8388624      E..V...... Multi-pass optimized for constant frame size (deprecated)
     vbr_2pass       8388640      E..V...... Multi-pass variable bitrate mode (deprecated)
     cbr_ld_hq       8            E..V...... Constant bitrate low delay high quality mode
     cbr_hq          16           E..V...... Constant bitrate high quality mode
     vbr_hq          32           E..V...... Variable bitrate high quality mode
  -rc-lookahead      <int>        E..V...... Number of frames to look ahead for rate-control (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -surfaces          <int>        E..V...... Number of concurrent surfaces (from 0 to 64) (default 0)
  -cbr               <boolean>    E..V...... Use cbr encoding mode (default false)
  -2pass             <boolean>    E..V...... Use 2pass encoding mode (default auto)
  -gpu               <int>        E..V...... Selects which NVENC capable GPU to use. First GPU is 0, second is 1, and so on. (from -2 to INT_MAX) (default any)
     any             -1           E..V...... Pick the first device available
     list            -2           E..V...... List the available devices
  -delay             <int>        E..V...... Delay frame output by the given amount of frames (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default INT_MAX)
  -no-scenecut       <boolean>    E..V...... When lookahead is enabled, set this to 1 to disable adaptive I-frame insertion at scene cuts (default false)
  -forced-idr        <boolean>    E..V...... If forcing keyframes, force them as IDR frames. (default false)
  -b_adapt           <boolean>    E..V...... When lookahead is enabled, set this to 0 to disable adaptive B-frame decision (default true)
  -spatial-aq        <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Spatial AQ (default false)
  -spatial_aq        <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Spatial AQ (default false)
  -temporal-aq       <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Temporal AQ (default false)
  -temporal_aq       <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Temporal AQ (default false)
  -zerolatency       <boolean>    E..V...... Set 1 to indicate zero latency operation (no reordering delay) (default false)
  -nonref_p          <boolean>    E..V...... Set this to 1 to enable automatic insertion of non-reference P-frames (default false)
  -strict_gop        <boolean>    E..V...... Set 1 to minimize GOP-to-GOP rate fluctuations (default false)
  -aq-strength       <int>        E..V...... When Spatial AQ is enabled, this field is used to specify AQ strength. AQ strength scale is from 1 (low) - 15 (aggressive) (from 1 to 15) (default 8)
  -cq                <float>      E..V...... Set target quality level (0 to 51, 0 means automatic) for constant quality mode in VBR rate control (from 0 to 51) (default 0)
  -aud               <boolean>    E..V...... Use access unit delimiters (default false)
  -bluray-compat     <boolean>    E..V...... Bluray compatibility workarounds (default false)
  -init_qpP          <int>        E..V...... Initial QP value for P frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -init_qpB          <int>        E..V...... Initial QP value for B frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -init_qpI          <int>        E..V...... Initial QP value for I frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -qp                <int>        E..V...... Constant quantization parameter rate control method (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -weighted_pred     <int>        E..V...... Set 1 to enable weighted prediction (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
  -coder             <int>        E..V...... Coder type (from -1 to 2) (default default)
     default         -1           E..V......
     auto            0            E..V......
     cabac           1            E..V......
     cavlc           2            E..V......
     ac              1            E..V......
     vlc             2            E..V......
  -b_ref_mode        <int>        E..V...... Use B frames as references (from 0 to 2) (default disabled)
     disabled        0            E..V...... B frames will not be used for reference
     each            1            E..V...... Each B frame will be used for reference
     middle          2            E..V...... Only (number of B frames)/2 will be used for reference
  -a53cc             <boolean>    E..V...... Use A53 Closed Captions (if available) (default true)
  -dpb_size          <int>        E..V...... Specifies the DPB size used for encoding (0 means automatic) (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I'm looking for a way to specify scenecut and keyframe interval when using nvenc. Previously, when using libx264, I was doing it this way -x264-params keyint=50:scenecut=0. But I can't find a way to do the same with nvenc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-g` is a generic option for codecs and should be used here. `-g` is nominated in frames.

`-h encoder=X` will only list private options of `X`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Just tested using -g and validated the output using ffprobe. Thank you!
Here's an example command of 1 input to N outputs for those looking for an answer. I'm using 25fps, so -g 50 sets keyframe interval to 2 seconds.
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda  -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf scale_npp=1920:1080 -c:v h264_nvenc -g 50 -b:v 5M -maxrate 5.5M -minrate 4M -bufsize 5M -preset fast 1080p_output.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf scale_npp=1280:720 -c:v h264_nvenc -g 50 -b:v 3.4M -maxrate 4M -minrate 3M -bufsize 3.4M -preset fast 720p_output.mp4